# Image center aligned vertically and horizontally with responsiveness

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

It is responsive on chrome, but IE 10 does not respond on image resize.

as well as if the image is bigger, then initially the max-width: 100% and max-height: 100% is not working...

Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="imagewrap">
            <div class="imagefluid">
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Dallas-Reunion.jpg" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {margin:0;padding:0}
html,body{height:100%}
.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.outer{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.imagewrap{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.imagefluid{
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Here is the fiddle.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/a5mgS/4/

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you want something like http://fiddle.jshell.net/PYAA7/ ?

Comment: For `display: table`, I think you need to structure the elements like a table, with both a `table row` and a `table cell`. See: http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html#table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
.imagewrap{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    float:left;
}
.imagefluid{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    text-align:right;
    left:-50%;
}

.imagefluid img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot first, it solves the first problem now image is responsive in IE also.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's feasible or not, but you can use Bootstrap 3.  Apply the class "img-responsive" and it'll behave as you want.  Works in all browsers IE8 and above